# Why do protons need to moving at high speed to collide?

Tags: particle-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider

I want to know Why protons need to moving at high speed to collide?

I know that both protons are positively charged so the electrostatic repulsive force would tend to make them miss each other at lower velocities, but I don't think this really answers my question.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that doesn’t answer your question?

Comment: How high speed? How do you know this from? (ref?)

Comment: Protons also collide at low speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, to get two protons to collide "head on" hard enough so that the quarks inside them can interact requires tremendous force. To see this (here's your homework!) take the equation for the electrostatic force between two (identically charged) objects and use for the distance between them the diameter of a proton, and solve. The answer will give you an *estimate* of the *lower bound* for the required force.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is important to understand that by saying colliding protons, you are not saying that you are colliding them like two balls. Particle collision means that particles scatter from one another. Or in other words, make them interact. Or even in the words of the quantum field theory, make them exchange a particle, which is in the case of two protons typically a photon (a carrier of the electromagnetic interaction).

Now, you do not need them to have high energies to scatter. The Coulomb force has an infinite range ($F = \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$). However, really interesting things happen when they get close together.

For example, one proton could undergo a beta plus decay and transform into a neutron emitting a positron (anti-electron) and an electron neutrino. Further, proton and neutron would bound together and form a Deuterium nucleus ($_1^2D$ Hydrogen atom isotope). To make this happen you need to make them come close enough around the scale of the Deuterium nucles radius $r \backsim 2\cdot 10^{-15}m$.

Answer (score 0):

What is "to collide" ?
Let's consider the speeds as 2 opposed components of a force that can: scatter or merge or annihilated both protons.
To scatter, the energy of the combined force is less than the electrostatic Coulomb force that repels both positive charged particules.
To merge in a diproton nucleus (starting a fusion chain reaction) without breaking the protons,the collision force must be higher than the electrostatic repulsion force but lower than a force that would breaks the protons and let quarks and gluons rearrange and the cinetic energy of collision generates new particules.
Now what are the value of those 2 thresholds ? For the first threshold, the repulsion electrostatic force is dominant until one reaches an horizon nearby the proton where the strong attractive nuclear force becomes dominant. There are sites that have compute the radius of this horizon and determine ne force need for two protons on the same speed vector direction to colide and fusion.

Hereby the article of wikipedia on proton to proton fusion concept that documents this question and the research done around it.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colliding_beam_fusion

For the collision force use in particle research, please google on this topic... The required energy is dictated by the reaction product that you want to examined.